# How to get Field names from a SQL database into a list in python

Tags: python, mysql

Here is a the code I have so far:

```
from ConfigParser import *
import MySQLdb

configuration = ConfigParser()
configuration.read('someconfigfile.conf')
    db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host = configuration.get('DATABASE', 'MYSQL_HOST'),
    user = configuration.get('DATABASE', 'MYSQL_USER'),
    passwd = configuration.get('DATABASE', 'MYSQL_PASS'),
    db = configuration.get('DATABASE', 'MYSQL_DB'),
    port = configuration.getint('DATABASE', 'MYSQL_PORT'),
    ssl = {
        'ca':   configuration.get('SSL_SETTINGS', 'SSL_CA'),
        'cert': configuration.get('SSL_SETTINGS', 'SSL_CERT'),
        'key':  configuration.get('SSL_SETTINGS', 'SSL_KEY')
            },
    )
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name='met';"
cursor.execute(sql)
list = cursor.fetchall()

print list
```

this is what prints:

```
(('field',), ('field',), ('field',), ('field',), ('field',), ('field',), ('field',), ('field',), ('field',), ('field',), ('field',), ('field',), ('field',), ('field',), ('pk_wind_spd2',), ('field',))
```

And I am getting a tuple instead of a list. I would prefer to have a list of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't shadow built-ins (list), change to

`alist = cursor.fetchall()`

This generator expression will get you the column names in a tuple:

`tuple(i[0] for i in alist)`

Comment: Think you ment list(i[0] for i in alist) anyways I am giving a check mark for leading me in the right direction

Comment: @Richard: sure you can make it a list if you like. In that case you can simply use a list-comprehension and the code is even shorter:  `[i[0] for i in alist]`.